# Why couldn't I remove the Listeners?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

Hi I write a Whiteboard where you can draw on in vue. I use svg to paint paths. It does work with my EventHandlers, but i want to remove the Handlers, when i make my mouse up. The app should work like, when you click, the Whiteboard gets all Eventhandlers and you can paint a line. When you dont click you dont paint. At the moment i make a undendless line, when i clicked once.

I hope this is understandable :/

Thanks

```
main() {
      // hole whiteboard
      let whiteboard = document.getElementById("whiteboard");
      const color = "black";



      let test2 = event => {
                //console.log(event);
        this.createSvgElement(whiteboard, color);
        this.setup(event);
        //alert("Ich bin reich!");
      }

            whiteboard.addEventListener("mousedown", test2);

    },
    createSvgElement(w, c){
            this.whiteboard.removeEventListener("mousedown", this);
      this.whiteboard = w;
      this.segments = [];
      this.points = [];

      this.path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");

      this.path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", c);
      this.path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "2");
      this.path.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "transparent");
            //console.log(this.path);


    },
    setup(event){
      this.whiteboard.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
                const [x, y] = this.pos(e);
            //console.log(x);
            this.points.push({ x, y });
                        const test = this.path.getAttributeNS(null, "d");
                        //console.log(test);
            this.path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", test + ` L${x},${y}`);
            });


            this.whiteboard.addEventListener("mouseleave", e =>{
                this.whiteboard.removeEventListener("mousemove", this);
        this.whiteboard.removeEventListener("mouseup", this);
        this.whiteboard.removeEventListener("mouseleave", this);
            });

            this.whiteboard.addEventListener("mouseup", e =>{
                this.whiteboard.removeEventListener("mousemove", this);
        this.whiteboard.removeEventListener("mouseup", this);
        this.whiteboard.removeEventListener("mouseleave", this);
            });



    }, 
    pos(e){
      const rect = this.whiteboard.getBoundingClientRect();
      return [e.clientX - rect.left, e.clientY - rect.top];
    },
```

Comment: Maybe instead of adding and removing listeners all the time you should try to keep track of whether the mouse is clicked or not with a variable, and check it in your events

Comment: The 2nd argument to `removeEventListener()` must be a function, and it has to be the same function that was used in `addEventListener()`. This usually requires that it be a named function, not an anonymous function.

Comment: `this` is the object containing all these methods, not the listener function. So what listener do you expect `removeEventListener("mousedown", this)` to remove?

Comment: It should be something like `this.whiteboard.removeEventListener("mousedown", test2);`

Answer (score 1):

When you handle the `mousedown` event for a particular element, you aren't guaranteed to receive the corresponding `mouseup` event on that same element because the mouse button may be released while the pointer is over a different element, or even outside the window entirely.

The only API to allow you to do this is [setCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture), though that is very non-standard.

The recommended way to handle mouse events like this is to attach the `mousemove` and `mouseup` events to the document element while the mouse is down on the target element. This works because mouse events will bubble up, and `mouseup` will be fired on the document even when the pointer is outside the browser window.

Simplified:

```js
const onMouseDown = e => {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp)
}

const onMouseUp = e => {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp)
}

const onMouseMove = e => {
  // Handle move event
}

this.whiteboard.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown)
```

You also have an error with the way you are calling `removeEventListener`:

> ```
> this.whiteboard.removeEventListener("mousemove", this)
>                                                  ^^^^
> ```

The second argument should be the event listener function that you want to remove; `this` is the component object instance.